# Find based on calculated difference

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to query my Mongo DB based on some parameters. However, to get the parameter, I first need to use a find() anyway and then do some calculations.

This, obviously, is not efficient.

Let me elaborate:

Here is my collection I want to query:

```
{
  "title": "1",
  "description": "1",
  "aCounter": 100,
  "bCounter": 20,
  "__v": 0
}
```

I want to find posts where **aCounter - bCounter** is more than **50**.

I have the model and everything ready but don't know about what to put in the find() parameters.

```
postModel.find({
  //I don't know what to put here
})
.exec(function(err, posts) {
  if(posts){
    //return the data
  }
});
```

Any input will help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

Use [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)

```
postModel.find({ "$where": "(this.aCounter - this.bCounter) > 50" })
```

or actually more performant to use [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) with `.aggregate()`:

```
postModel.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": { 
      "if": {
        "$gt": [
          { "$subtract": [ "$aCounter", "$bCounter" ] },
          50
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

The latter is better really because it uses "native coded" operators as opposed to the JavaScript evaluation that [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) uses.

Where possible though, both should be combined with a regular query expression since neither can actually use an index to speed results on it's own.

Comment: Solution 2 worked for me. Thanks. I have some other issues (need to nest the arithmetic calculations to find the ratio) but I didn't wanna hijack this post.

Comment: @ShayanKhan And so you [should not when an answer addresses the actual question asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252113/2313887). If you have different requirements then the correct procedure is either 1. Learn from the answer given in order to apply your actual requirement not represented in the question. 2. [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you are unsure how to adapt the answer to your actual requirement. Under no circumstance should you ever A. Change your post, or the answer B. Provide an answer to different requirements than the question asked for.

Comment: Got it mate. Thanks