# Mongo/Mongoose - Nested Arithmetic calculations in $redact

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I posted a question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116525/find-based-on-calculated-difference), which has been answered.

Now, I want to take the same approach to calculate the ratio of the like's (in comparison to the total) and only show the records where the like's ratio is more then 40 and less than 60.

I thought the below should work but it isn't:

```
postModel.aggregate([
  { $redact: {
    $cond: {
      and: {
        $lt: [ {$divide: {$multiply: [$likeCounter, 100]}, $add: [$likeCounter, $dislikeCounter] }, 60],
        $gt: [ {$divide: {$multiply: [$likeCounter, 100]}, $add: [$likeCounter, $dislikeCounter] }, 40]
     },
     then: $$KEEP,
     else: $$PRUNE
     }
     }}
     .exec(function(err, posts) {
        if (err){
          console.log(err);//There is no output for this
        } else {
          console.log(posts);//There is no output for this
        }
     })
   ]);
```

I am pretty certain the issue is with the **$redact** bit but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I don't get a console output from **err** nor **posts**.

I have made sure the function calling this is being called by putting a *console.log* there.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$cond` expression is not correctly formatted.

Includes missing `if` keyword, `[]` around arithmetic operands and quotes around aggregation variables.

Try replacing your `$cond` with below.

```
{
  "$cond": {
    "if": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "$lt": [
            {
              "$divide": [
                {
                  "$multiply": [
                    "$likeCounter",
                    100
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$add": [
                    "$likeCounter",
                    "$dislikeCounter"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            60
          ]
        },
        {
          "$gt": [
            {
              "$divide": [
                {
                  "$multiply": [
                    "$likeCounter",
                    100
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$add": [
                    "$likeCounter",
                    "$dislikeCounter"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            40
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": "$$KEEP",
    "else": "$$PRUNE"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for spotting that! However, and weirdly enough, I'm still having the same damn issue. There is no output in the logs whatsoever. Any further ideas mate?

Comment: np. One more thing is that you have to call `exec` on `aggregate`. So something like  `aggregate([your query]).exec(your function);`

Comment: Yeah I have that (original question). Why it's still not working, I haven't a clue. I will see if something comes up. Was thinking at least the "err" should've been consoled out.

Comment: Okay. Check your data and make sure your formula is right and your query conditions are correct.

Comment: Shall do sir. Thanks